# Most efficient way to toggle aria-pressed role in React for web accessibility

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a bunch of divs and spans that I'm using as buttons and need to toggle between the aria-pressed state of "true" and "false". Of course, it's possible to do this using this aria-pressed={this.state.pressed}, but this would require me to have aria state for each button (there are many).

My alternative solution was to use a ternary and conditionally render different divs. For example,

```
{ this.state.buttonChange? <div onClick=(this.buttonChange} aria-pressed="true></div> : <div onClick=(this.buttonChange} aria-pressed="false"></div>}
```

But this would create a lot of duplicated code and maybe be less efficient than just having a bunch of different aria states.

What is the most efficient way of handling this problem in React without using a native html button element?

Comment: Trust me, you do not want to conditionally render. The buttons will lose any potential focus states, which makes them very keyboard inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div onClick=(this.buttonChange} aria-pressed={this.state.buttonChange}></div>
```

so you only need to set the aria-pressed value based on the state.

Answer (score 2):

One way which I think is using ternary operator with assigning div elements to a variable for reusability

```
let button = <div onClick=(this.buttonChange} aria-pressed={this.state.pressed}></div>;
{ this.state.buttonChange? {button} : {button}}
```

Or if you are rendering buttons dynamically based on dynamic data then you can push all div elements to an array and render it.